# I need to update an id field for a table, without touching any other fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `_field`. Now, for some reason, a field inside the table called `block` got messy and now contains the wrong block numbers. 
I have the default data for `_field`, but some of the other fields can no longer be at default because of foreign constraints and stuff, so, I can't just restore the default data.
So, for now, I created a new table called `tmp_field` and populated it with the default `_field` data.

Now, I need a query that takes the data from `_field` and changes all of the `block` numbers in `_field` to match the `block` numbers from `tmp_field`.

Another way to phrase it would be:
It checks each row of `_field` and if some field (like `fieldid` or `name`) matches the same field in `tmp_field`, then it changes the value of block in `_field` to match the value of block in `tmp_field`.

Note: I am using Postgresql 9.1.

Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE _field
    SET block = tmp_field.block
    FROM tmp_field
    WHERE _field.fieldid = tmp_field.fieldid
        OR _field.name = tmp_field.name
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, especially for the quick response. I tried something similar, but it didn't work because I didn't know about the `FROM` clause. Also, `fieldid` needs to be `_field.fieldid`, the same with `name`, but yeah, this works. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @zermy: Updated answer per your comment.